# Reading and parsing complex JSON - Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I've been trying to read this complex JSON Data in Swift, which i can read the "feed" and then "entry" until reaching "url" for each element in the JSON.

This is the JSON (Dictionary - Array - Dictionary - Array - Dictionary ):

```
{
  "feed": {
    "entry": [
      {
        "media$group": {
          "media$content": [
            {
              "url": "http://..../photo.png"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my Photo Class where i define the things i need to get from JSON:

```
class Photo {

    let TAG_FEED:String = "feed"
    let TAG_ENTRY:String = "entry"
    let TAG_MEDIA_GROUP:String = "media$group"
    let TAG_MEDIA_CONTENT:String = "media$content"
    let TAG_IMG_URL:String = "url"
}
```

This is my `UIViewController` where I'm trying to read the JSON :

```
func parseJsonData(data: NSData) -> [Photo] {
        var photos = [Photo]()
        var error:NSError?

        let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as? NSDictionary

        if error != nil {
            println(error?.localizedDescription)
        }

        // how is it possible to read it here 


        return photos
    }
```

After reading the array is it possible to store it array of Strings.

Comment: What is your problem? The JSON serialization does not return what you want? BTW you can read data from an `NSDictionary` with the methods `valueForKey` and `objectForKey`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to parse then use below piece of code and learn.

```
if let myFeed = jsonResult[TAG_FEED] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
  if let myEntries = myFeed[TAG_ENTRY] as? Array<AnyObject> {
     for myEntry in myEntries {
         if let myMedia = myEntry[TAG_MEDIA_GROUP] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            if let contents = myMedia[TAG_MEDIA_CONTENT] as? Array<AnyObject> {
               for myContent in contents {
                   if let url = myContent[TAG_IMG_URL] as? String {

                     // populate your model class here...

                  }
              }
           }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Change your jsonResult line to `let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: &error) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>!`

Comment: it gives an error when writing instead of TAG_FEED -> "feed" , `'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?' is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'`

Comment: Please define these constants out side the Photo class and check.

Comment: i define it in the UIViewController and it says  `'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?' is not convertible to 'NSCopying'`

Comment: Code looks fine, please replace this line         let jsonResult: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: &error)

Comment: it says : `Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments `

Comment: This is because jsonResult is of type AnyObject?. So please change it to Dictionary<String,AnyObject>?. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77416/discussion-between-amit89-and-aaoii).

Answer (score 0):

As alternative you can use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)